# How to deal with promoted conflicting branches on jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, promoted-builds

The idea is:

1. all devs work on their feature branches and push them to github
2. jenkins starts builds (triggered by "push on github") on job **test** to run unit tests on those feature branches
3. Once they pass the test, manager goes to github to do code review.
4. If code review is fine, then this build is promoted(promote build plugin) manually to "Pass QA, Ready for prod", in "actions" section, we set "trigger/call builds on other projects" to trigger a separate job **test-prod** only to merge this feature branch to master on remote repo.

job **test** promote build config:
[image]

job **test-prod** SCM config:
[image]

So 2 questions here:

1. on step 4, we have situations like 2 conflicting feature branches both passed code review,  the first branch that is promoted will be fine, but the second will have conflicts and failure, is there a way to detect conflict before?  I know 'merge before build' can avoid conflict but that requires the former branch already been merged to remote master
2. in no-conflict cases, whenever the second job is triggered by the manually promotion, there is always an extra build caused by: "Legacy code started this job. No cause information is available", I have no idea how that happens.

Also, dont know whether the idea is correct in terms of whole pipeline, any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: This may be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204729/legacy-code-started-this-job-no-cause-information-is-available

Comment: Hey user, we just figured out the cause of the `"Legacy code started this job"` in the above linked answer. See if that applies to you as well. He had `Build when another project is promoted` configured, which you shouldn't use when using `Trigger/Call builds`

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I know nothing about git.*

According to **[this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dev+Good+Practice)**, the best practice is to use `rebase`. As I am not familiar with git, I can't tell you how to setup `rebase` on Jenkins.

There is another poster here that also has issues with git and "Legacy code started this job" triggering extra builds: **[Legacy code started this job. No cause information is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204729/legacy-code-started-this-job-no-cause-information-is-available)**.